# Meaning of "We rang changes everyday"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

From novel *To Kill a Mockingbird*:

> As the summer progressed, so did our game. We polished and perfected it, added dialogue and plot until we had manufactured a small play **upon which we rang changes every day**.

What does *we rang changes every day* mean? Rang seems to be a verb (past tense of ring), meaning making some sound, but change is also a verb, which makes it a verb+verb?

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a variation of the idiom [ring the changes](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ring+the+changes), which means to make something more interesting by changing it a little bit. *changes* is a plural noun here, it's not a verb. So, I presume what your passage is saying is that they invented the play and used it to even more change their life at the hospital in some way on a daily basis to make it more fun.

Comment: Not in American English!  As per the page you linked, the idiom "ring the changes" means to make more interesting in the British and Australian use. In American English, "to ring the changes" means to go through all possible permutations of something (which is what change ringing, in the original sense referring to bells, literally means) with an implication of obsessing/reveling over details. Though I don't think it pertains in this example, the AmEng sense can be used to imply that which is so described is tedious and the variations meaningless.  And the source text in question is AmEng.